# How to add custom html files similar to the html files generated by Next.js static export build?

Tags: next.js

I want to add custom html files in the out folder created by Next.js static export build. As Next.js creates html files in static export build, i want to create some of the dynamic pages using the getStaticPath and getStaticProps and rest of the pages for same dynamic routes manually rather than using the static build again. As the project have a lot of dynamic pages it takes a lot of time to build all the pages using export build.

I tried to copy the generated files and paste it again with different data and it displayed the updated data but not always so i want to make sure it should work properly along with routing.